# Microsoft.Build.BuildEngine ignores BeforeTargets

Tags: c#, f#, msbuild, msbuild-4.0, microsoft.build

Building a project file with the `Microsoft.Build.BuildEngine` library seems to be ignoring the `BeforeTargets` attribute.

My project file has the following target:

```
<Target Name="MyTestTarget" BeforeTargets="Build">
  <Message Importance="High" Text="Running MyTestTarget" />
</Target>
```

and when I compile it with the following code (F#, but does the same in C#):

```ml
open System
open Microsoft.Build.BuildEngine
open Microsoft.Build.Framework

[<EntryPoint; STAThread>]
let main argv =
    let engine = new Engine()
    engine.RegisterLogger(new ConsoleLogger())
    let project = new Project(engine)
    project.Load("MyProjectFile.fsproj")
    let succeeded = engine.BuildProject(project, "Build")
    0
```

the target `"MyTestTarget"` is not run. Note that when I use `MSBuild.exe` 4.0 instead, `"MyTestTarget"` is correctly run.

I know that BeforeTargets was added in MSBuild 4.0, and would throw an exception if used with an older version of `Microsoft.Build`. But I haven't found anything about BeforeTargets being ignored by MSBuild 4.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're using deprecated types, if you use the new types then it works:

```
let projects = new ProjectCollection()
projects.RegisterLogger(new ConsoleLogger())
let project = projects.LoadProject("MyProjectFile.fsproj")
let succeeded = project.Build("Build")
```

If you didn't see any warnings about deprecated types, then perhaps you are referencing older versions of the MSBuild assemblies.

Comment: I do see the warnings, and I know those are deprecated. However my code needs to run on mono, and the newer APIs such as `ProjectCollection` are not implemented there yet. Moreover, I don't have any warning or error about `BeforeTargets` being an unknown attribute, which is what happens (based on my googling) when using older assemblies.

Comment: It turns out that the mono implementation of `BuildEngine` doesn't have this bug. So I am now implementing two code paths, one for mono using `BuildEngine` and one for .NET using `Execution`.